# makefile with 2 targets and if statement,error why?

Tags: linux, makefile

Makefile:

`a b:
        if [ -f s ];then
        echo aaa
        fi`

command:make  b

`if [ -f s ];then
   /bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
   make: *** [b] Error 2`

Could anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be mixing shell scripting and make scripting. Try the below

```
a b:
        @if test -f s; then \
             echo "aaa";\
        fi
```